# TestNg Rerun of Failed cases

Tags: automation, automated-tests, frameworks, testng, testng.xml

I have a framework say there are 200 cases which run in parallel on testng and 5 failed and I want to run them after the execution of these 200 cases are over.
Also I want to get a single report of the execution ime 3 out of 5 passes on re-execution then report would show 198 passed ,2 failed.

Can you guide me as how to achive this.
I have come across retry analyser but that will not solve this purpose.

Comment: Please include more details like what you have tried using `RetryAnalzyer` and why you think it will not solve the issue.

Comment: Retry analyser is being used if run a test case and if it fails it will rerun immediately.What I want to achieve is that the entire suite is run then only after that failed test case will rerun only once.

Comment: Adding the code you have tried so far in the question would be good. Also please mention the reason why you want it to run only after entire suite is executed instead of retrying immediately